# Permission Issue Rails 7.0.3.1

Tags: postgresql, rubygems

I am getting this error while Building New Rails App with PostgreSQL please help:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using marcel 1.0.2
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using digest 3.1.0
Using timeout 0.3.0
Using minitest 5.16.2
Using public_suffix 4.0.7
Using crass 1.0.6
Using rack 2.2.4
Using bundler 2.3.17
Using erubi 1.11.0
Using racc 1.6.0
Using strscan 3.0.4
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using io-console 0.5.11
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using builder 3.2.4
Using matrix 0.4.2
Using regexp_parser 2.5.0
Using childprocess 4.1.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using msgpack 1.5.4
Using thor 1.2.1
Using zeitwerk 2.6.0
Using redis 4.7.1
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using net-protocol 0.1.3
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using i18n 1.12.0
Using tzinfo 2.0.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using mail 2.7.1
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using websocket 1.2.9
Using rack-test 2.0.2
Using sprockets 4.1.1
Using nokogiri 1.13.8 (x86_64-linux)
Using net-smtp 0.3.1
Using reline 0.3.1
Using bootsnap 1.13.0
Using net-imap 0.2.3
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using irb 1.4.1
Using puma 5.6.4
Using debug 1.6.1
Using loofah 2.18.0
Using net-pop 0.1.1
Using activesupport 7.0.3.1
Using capybara 3.37.1
Using globalid 1.0.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
Using selenium-webdriver 4.3.0
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using webdrivers 5.0.0
Using actionview 7.0.3.1
Using activemodel 7.0.3.1
Using activejob 7.0.3.1
Using activerecord 7.0.3.1
Using jbuilder 2.11.5
Using actionpack 7.0.3.1
Using activestorage 7.0.3.1
Using actionmailer 7.0.3.1
Using actionmailbox 7.0.3.1
Using actiontext 7.0.3.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
Using actioncable 7.0.3.1
Using railties 7.0.3.1
Using rails 7.0.3.1
Using turbo-rails 1.1.1
Using importmap-rails 1.1.5
Using web-console 4.2.0
Using stimulus-rails 1.1.0
Installing pg 1.4.2 with native extensions
Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of
`/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.2`.
The underlying error was Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_rmdir -
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.2/sample, with backtrace:
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1459:in
`rmdir'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1459:in
`block in remove_dir1'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1470:in
`platform_support'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1458:in
`remove_dir1'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1451:in
`remove'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:780:in
`block in remove_entry'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1503:in
`block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1508:in
`ensure in postorder_traverse'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1508:in
`postorder_traverse'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1502:in
`block in postorder_traverse'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1501:in
`each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1501:in
`postorder_traverse'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:778:in
`remove_entry'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:698:in
`remove_entry_secure'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler.rb:331:in `rm_rf'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:104:in
`strict_rm_rf'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in
`install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:209:in
`install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
`block in worker_pool'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in
process_queue'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2
levels) in create_threads'

Bundler Error Backtrace:
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:106:in
`rescue in strict_rm_rf'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:103:in
`strict_rm_rf'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in
`install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:209:in
`install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
`block in worker_pool'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in
process_queue'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.17/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2
levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing pg (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

Comment: Can you manually remove `/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.2` directory? Also, it looks that you are using system Ruby. If this is your development environment, perhaps you can try `rvm` or `rbenv`. When I switched to using `rvm`, it made a huge difference for me as I no longer needed sudo access; everything was installed in my home directory

Comment: How can I manually remove /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.2 directory? How can I access it using GUI? Any Idea? I am restricted to use gem .

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.2` from terminal (assuming you are on Linux)

Comment: gem install pg

Building native extensions. This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing pg:

 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.2/ext

/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20220804-12329-116mcg2.rb extconf.rb

Calling libpq with GVL unlocked

This error